# Inserting nested JSON data into html dropdown

Tags: html, json, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a JSON string like this:

```
{
"electronics": {
    "cameras": [
        "sony",
        "nikon",
        "canon"
    ],
    "TV": "none",
    "laptop": [
        "hp",
        "apple",
        "sony"
    ]
},
"home": {
    "furniture": [
        "table",
        "chair",
        "cupboard"
    ],
    "couch": "none",
    "utensils": "none"
},
"books": {
    "educations": [
        "geography",
        "science"
    ],
    "magazines": "none"
},
"kids": {
    "toys": [
        "games",
        "building toys",
        "dolls & accessories",
        "baby & toddler"
    ],
    "clothes": "none"
},
"sports": {
    "outdoor": "none",
    "exercise": [
        "footwear",
        "clothing",
        "yogas & DVDs"
    ]
},
"photos": {
    "cards & invitations": "none",
    "canvas wall art": "none",
    "mugs": "none"
}
```

}

I want to display the list as dropdown using bootstrap.
The HTML code using bootstrap with hardcoded values is as follows.

```
 <li class="dropdown"  style="width:140px;">
                    <a class= "dropdown-toggle dropdown-menu-hover-color menu-left-color"  data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Electronics </a>

                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="position:absolute;float:right;top: 0; left: 140px; ">
                        <li>
                            <a class="dropdown-level1-color menu-left-color" href= "#">Laptop</a> 
                            <ul type="none">
                                <li><a href="#">Apple</a></li> 
                                <li><a href="#">Sony</a></li> 
                                <li><a href="#">HP</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="dropdown-level1-color menu-left-color" href=  "#">Camera</a>
                            <ul type="none">
                                <li><a href="#">Canon</a></li> 
                                <li><a href="#">Nikon</a></li> 
                                <li><a href="#">Sony</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li> 
                        <li><a class="dropdown-level1-color menu-left-color" href= "#">TV</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
```

I wan to populate the values from the JSON into the HTML code using AngularJS.
Any pointers to implementation will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Look at http://json.bloople.net/, the page offers an online converter JSON -> HTML and provides the link to the source.

BTW: any reason why "Electronics", "Home", .. are objects and not arrays.

Comment: Actually I wanted a combination of  HTML code using AngularJS , i have reedited the question again. No specific reason for  "Electronics", "Home", .. are objects, I just wanted to maintain a hierarchy.